# Java hexadecimal velue convert to ascii and back to hexadecimal goes wrong

Tags: java, char, hex, ascii

I made a little project that converts a hexadecimal string into an ASCII string. When i convert te value then i send it to a client. But my client doesn't reconised the value.

I searched why and i saw that when i convert the ASCII string back to hexadecimal, then i get a little bit differend value back .. So i think something has going wrong when i sended the data .. But i don't no how to fix my problem ..

I also tried to convert the hex first to dec and then to ascii , also i tried the more noob whay , just send a command with for example this :

```
char p = 3;
char d = 4;

bw3.write(p + "" + c + "");
```

So this is the code i get now :

```
  ServerSocket welcomeSocket2 = new ServerSocket(9999);
   Socket socket2 = welcomeSocket2.accept();  
   OutputStream os3 = socket2.getOutputStream();
   OutputStreamWriter osw3 = new OutputStreamWriter(os3);
   BufferedWriter bw3 = new BufferedWriter(osw3);




 String hex4 = "00383700177a0102081c4200000000000001a999c338030201000a080000000000000000184802000007080444544235508001000002080104";

   StringBuilder output4 = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i =0; i< hex4.length(); i +=2){
       String str4 = hex4.substring(i, i+2);
       int outputdecimal = Integer.parseInt(str4,16);
       char hexchar = (char)outputdecimal;
       System.out.println(str4);
       output4.append(hexchar);
   }

  bw3.write(output4.toString());
   bw3.flush();
```

What i also noticed is that when i send a command that is only 4 bytes long or 10 then everything is going good. I receive my converted ascii code good. The command that i now wanne send is 58 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is not capable to represent all possible data expressed in hexadecimal.

Therefore, as long as you'll try to convert your hexa to ASCII, nothing you try will ever work.

Your hexadecimal contain purely binary, computer-y opaque data. ASCII is what you use to represent text. There are some binary data that are made out of ASCII and therefore can be represented in ASCII. And there are all the other data than these ones. Those will always end up wrong when you try to convert hexadecimal to ASCII. This is simply because ASCII is meant to be unable to do that, by the very definition of what it is.

Comment: but if i send for example only a value of 10 bytes long everything workes , why is that ? because you say to me if i convert hex to ascii nothing i try will work , but other smaller commands does work , also i tried decimal to ascii , normally there you can convert 0 - 255 in ascii

Comment: @metalgastje Because you've chosen by chance a 10 bytes long chunk of data that is entirely made out of ASCII. These things happen, ASCII is ubiquitous in computers. However, ASCII is not what every data is made of, so you're bound to frequently run in cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: okay but the hexadecimal string that i have can be converted to ascii , 00 - ascii 00 , 38 --> 8 , so i don't get why he does it not good when i convert back from ascii to hex , and also , if ascii doesn't work , i witch type most i send my data then ?

Comment: Is the hexadecimal String that you have, the one put in variable hex4? Because it cannot be converted to ASCII. It contains byte a9, value 169, byte 99, value 153, byte c3, value 195, and byte 80, value 128. All of these are incompatible with ASCII, which defines characters for values 0 to 127 and nothing else.

Comment: But you can get also extended ascii ? to 255

Comment: No such thing as extended ascii, but yes you can get character encodings that define characters for values beyond 127. The problem is that what you're relying on here, is ASCII. *Not* one such character encoding.

Comment: okay but i need a whay to pass this hex string , any idea ? Byte is also not possible i think - 127 - + 128 ?

Comment: @metalgastje byte is the natural way to go, actually. It's binary, and you're trying to handle binary. So far you were trying to handle binary through text, which is your problem. Just remove all text components. Replace StringBuilder with a ByteArrayOutputStream, and remove OutputStreamWriter and BufferedWriter, to just use OutputStream as-is. Problem solved.